# RichTextBox make text multiple colours

Tags: c#, .net, wpf

I'm currently working on a messaging application with C# WPF. I am trying to insert text into a richTextBox, but apply different colours on the one line.

`[Billy123] The message`

I would like the text to be displayed on one line, as demonstrated, and have the username (in brackets) displayed in one colour, ie: red, then have the message displayed in a different colour, ie: black.

i tried doing the following twice:

```
run.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(Colors.Red); // My Color
Paragraph paragraph = new Paragraph(run);
MyRichTextBlock.Document.Blocks.Add(paragraph);
```

but this displayed the separate text as two parts, whereas i need them on one line.

i also tried:

```
            currentChatDisplay.AppendText("Loren");
            currentChatDisplay.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush(currentUserMessageColour);
            currentChatDisplay.AppendText("Loren");
```

(currentChatDisplay is the name of the RichTextBox) but it cdhanges the colour of ALL the text.

How would i go about achieving this?

EDIT: I have gone for the method demonstrated by @Peregrene in the comments

Comment: Does it have to be RichText? I've created an enhanced TextBlock control that will allow any text property, including foreground and background colours, to be set as desired using tags similar to HTML within the text - http://peregrinesview.uk/wpf-controls-formatted-textblock/

Comment: @Peregrine i took a look at your webpage, and it is perfect for my application! I'll probably choose this method, as i prefer the use of HTML syntax for formatting.

Comment: @Peregrine This control is pretty redundant. TextBlock already features to define the rich content as markup using the very fast XAML parser. Also there is the well established RTF text format which is usually displayed using the FlowDocument. If you reinvent the wheel it should be more powerful than the original (quality and maintenance aside).

Comment: @BionicCode Sure ... if you want to define your layout at design-time ... but how do you produce such output when the contents and formatting are not known until run-time?

Comment: @Peregrine One approach could be to use a binding converter that converts a string to the XAML layout of the TextBlock (inlines). Another approach is to create the TextBlock content based on TextPointers (or TextRanges). Another approach could be to use RTF compliant formed text as source for the TextBlock. In case of editing a rich formatted text, you would use the RichTextBox. But if the input is not intended to be edited directly by the user, then the TextBlock should be preferred.

Comment: @Peregrine TextBlock has the: TextBlock.Inlines property to build the content based on markup elements (XAML or C#), TextBlock.ContentStart to bulid the content based on TextPointer definitions, and finally convert the RTF file to a FlowDocument and add the content to a TextBlock using the TextBlock.ContentStart property.

Comment: @Peregrine Note that for bigger text (text that exceeds a few lines), TextBlock is not recommended as it is optimized to display small text portions only. The next performant text control to display larger rich formatted text is the FlowDocumentScrollViewer. It's a plain viewer and therefore more lightweight than the heavy RichTextBox.

Comment: @Peregrine Then there is the ListBox. When disabling the typical look&feel by removing item highlighting, you can render line based text using a TextBlock for each line/item. Since the ListBox offers UI virtualization, you get a very well performing read-only document viewer. - Just in case performance is an issue. FlowDocument and especially the RichTextBox can become very heavy quite easily.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to display colored text you don't need the heavy `RichTextBox`. Simply use a `TextBlock` and set the content using `TextBlock.Inlines`.
You would usually use a common `TextBox` as input. Then add this input to the colored message view, which is a `ListBox` that displays a `TextBlock` for each item i.e. message entry.

**XAML**

```
<TextBlock x:Name="ColoredTextBlock">
  <TextBlock.Inlines>
    <Run Text="Red text. " Foreground="Red" />
    <Run Text="Green text." Foreground="Green" />
  </TextBlock.Inlines>
</TextBlock>
```

**C#**

```
var coloredTextBlock = new TextBlock();
coloredTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Red text. ") { Foreground = Brushes.Red });
coloredTextBlock.Inlines.Add(new Run("Green text. ") { Foreground = Brushes.Green });
```

Answer (score 0):

The following worked for me with the name of my rtb as MyRichTextBox:

```
TextRange userName = new TextRange(MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        userName.Text = "[Billy123] ";
        userName.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Red);

        TextRange text = new TextRange(MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd, MyRichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
        text.Text = "The message";
        text.ApplyPropertyValue(TextElement.ForegroundProperty, Brushes.Black);
```

[image]

Comment: This was perfect! However, i've gone with the custom controls in the comments